Warehouse child theme issue prestashop 8
Has anyone ever encountered a problem with the latest Warehouse prestashop theme?
when creating a child from the basic theme
the child's layout is totaly different from the basic theme?
pestashop 8.1.1
Warehouse Advanced Multi-purpose Mega Electronics Store (loaded from prestashop addons)
Thanks
Contact developpers : answer should work

Using warehouse regularly with child themes in PS8, no problem so far. Make sure to use the zip package child theme sample which contains assets directory and font-awesome - Also check your child config.yml and make sure   "use_parent_assets" is set to "true"
